# Passenger failed to autodetect my nodejs application. dreamhost

Tags: node.js, passenger, dreamhost

I have bought a vps for my Nodejs server hosting and uploaded folder in my root directory `/home/username/domainname.com/`.

Inside of my domainname.com folder I also have app.js and activated passenger through domain management of my domain. I am not sure why passenger not picking my file. My server is working fine when I connect through Putty and run node app.js in domainname.com directory.

[image]